# How can I turn this const time conversion formula into a reusable function?

Tags: javascript, function, constants

I've been trying to turn the following simple millisecond to "minutes and seconds" conversion into a function. I'd like to use a function so I can easily send the milliseconds as a parameter and then return the formatted minutes and seconds.

```
const date = new Date(123456);
`${date.getMinutes()} minutes ${date.getSeconds()} seconds`; // Expected result: "2 minutes 3 seconds"
```

For the life of me I can't figure it out. I'm both seeking a short term solution and also an reason this isn't as simple as it seems, as I'm still very new to learning JavaScript.

Comment: Do you just want `ms` converted to minutes and seconds? If so using `Date` is not the way to go since it is tracking an offset from a datetime, not a duration.

Comment: @pilchard You're correct. I just want `ms` converted into a clean set of minutes and seconds. For example `61123` would return `1 minute 1 second`.

Comment: Then it is just a matter of arithmetic as covered in the duplicate :)

Comment: You should definitely **use arithmetic** instead of `Date`. [Leap seconds](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second) _will_ result in a difference between the expected duration and _time_ (of dates).

Answer (score 0):

Unless I missed the point, you can wrap it in a function declaration:

```js
function explainTime(milliseconds) {
  const date = new Date(milliseconds);
  return `${date.getMinutes()} minutes ${date.getSeconds()} seconds`;
}
```

You can then call this function with any number you want:

```js
const time1 = explainTime(1000); // 0 minutes 1 seconds
const time2 = explainTime(66000); // 1 minutes 6 seconds
```

Comment: If the OP is looking to convert ms to minutes and seconds this won't give the expected results `explainTime(1000 * 60 * 60);` -> `0 minutes 0 seconds` rather than `60 minutes 0 seconds`

Comment: This is still very helpful as it solved the issue I had with wrapping it in a function. I had made a very rookie mistake and didn’t see past it until both answers.